# Get the tag value of Edit text

Tags: android

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity  {
    AutoCompleteTextView cat;
    SimpleAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> values = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    EditText e1,e2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //name();

        cat = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.a_no);
        String[] from = { "NAME", "ID" };
        int[] to = { R.id.auto_id, R.id.auto_name };
        adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, values, R.layout.row,
                from, to);
        cat.setAdapter(adapter);
        cat.setThreshold(1);
        cat.setOnItemClickListener(autoItemSelectedListner);
    }


    private OnItemClickListener autoItemSelectedListner = new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {

            LinearLayout v1 = (LinearLayout) arg1.getParent();
            for (int i = 0; i < v1.getChildCount(); i++) {
                EditText e = (EditText) v1.getChildAt(i);
                Log.i("Tag Name IS", e.getTag().toString());

            }
        }

    };




}
```

**XML**

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/abc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

         <EditText
                android:id="@+id/other"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:tag="cde"
                android:hint="Other" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/a_no"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dip"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Account No" >
        </AutoCompleteTextView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Given a view I need to get the child views. I tried the above method and it works fine when I use `EditText`  but when I deal with auto complete it is not working. I am really stuck here. Your help will be highly appreciated(in this example I need to get the tag value of the `EditText`)

Comment: Tag value should R.id.edit_txt_name. eg: setTag(R.id.my_edit_text);
and then getTag(R.id.my_edit_text);

Comment: In my real example i create linear layout dynamically and each layout has 1 autocomplete and 2 edit text fields.So when i chose a value from autocomplete i need to change the value of edittext right next to auto complete.to do that i need to get the parent layout of the auto complte and get the edit textto be changed